# if window height, then change css height

Tags: jquery, css

i have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    var heightWithScrollBars = $(window).height();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');

    alert('heightWithScrollBars = ' + heightWithScrollBars);

    if ( heightWithScrollBars < 700 ){
       $(".vert, .simply-scroll-clip").height('270px'); 
   }        
});
```

there is a definition in a linked stylesheet - that those elements both have a height of 400px.

when the screen is indeed smaller than 700, the `if {}` does execute, but the height change does not execute.
but even if i run the exact line `$(".vert, .simply-scroll-clip").height('270px');` in the console - the command does indeed work. but not when it runs onload.

can anyone tell me why?

thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you forgot to wrap this in `$(document).ready()`. I'd also point out that this code will only run once, and you probably want to respond to the `window.resize` event to make this change.

Comment: "when it runs onload" You are wrapping code inside window onload event? If not, try that

Comment: correct, its within the `ready()` function, and yes, it will run once.

Comment: Still, try using: `$(window).on('load',function(){...});` instead of DOM ready handler and see if it makes a difference (waiting for any async elements as images to be fully loaded)

Comment: this works - can you explain why? pls add as answer, i will check off as such

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `viewport-width` with the `resize` event.

Apply the height in terms of vw

```
.vert, .simply-scroll-clip {
    height: 2vw;
}
```

And then resize

```
var causeRepaintsOn = $(".vert, .simply-scroll-clip");

$(window).resize(function() {
  causeRepaintsOn.css("z-index", 1);
});
```

Source: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) || Used this for a project once.